# KivMob Rewarded Video Ad listener

Tags: python, admob, kivy, kivy-language

I Am Trying to Implement Rewarded Video Ads on my kivy Application using KivMob.
I want to handle the callback functions of rewarded video ad by the RewardedListenerInterface provided in KivMob Library.

Here what I have done so far by my own understanding...

**Python Code**

```
class KivMobDemo(MDApp):

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    super().__init__(**kwargs)        

# These are our Admob Ad IDs
APP = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX"
BANNER = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
INTERSTITIAL = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX"
REWARDED_VIDEO = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX"
TEST_DEVICE_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Count = NumericProperty(0)  #The Count Variable
show_banner = False
ads = KivMob(APP)
def build(self):
    self.ads.add_test_device(self.TEST_DEVICE_ID)
    self.ads.new_banner(self.BANNER, False)
    self.ads.new_interstitial(self.INTERSTITIAL)
    self.ads.request_banner()
    self.ads.request_interstitial()
    self.ads.set_rewarded_ad_listener(RewardsHandler()) #passed the Rewards class object
    self.ads.load_rewarded_ad(self.REWARDED_VIDEO)
    self.toggled = False
    self.ads.show_banner()
    return KivMobDemoUI()

def toggle_banner(self):
    self.show_banner = not self.show_banner
    if self.show_banner:
        self.ads.show_banner()
     else:
         self.ads.hide_banner()

def load_video(self):
    self.ads.load_rewarded_ad(self.REWARDED_VIDEO)
```

**Made A Seperate Class For Overriding Callback Functions**

```
class RewardsHandler(RewardedListenerInterface):

def on_rewarded(self, reward_name, reward_amount):
    KivMobDemo.Count += reward_amount
    print("User rewarded")

def on_rewarded_video_ad_completed(self):
    self.on_rewarded("Reward",1)
    print("Ad Completed Time to give Rewards")

def on_rewarded_video_ad_closed(self):
    KivMobDemo.Count+=0

def on_rewarded_video_ad_left_application(self):
    KivMobDemo.Count = 0

def on_rewarded_video_ad_started(self):
    KivMobDemo().load_video()

def on_rewarded_video_ad_failed_to_load(self, error_code):
    if(error_code == 0):
        print("Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again")
    elif(error_code == 1):
        print("Please Report To the Developer")
    elif(error_code == 2):
        print("Make Sure You Have Internet Access")
    else:
        print("Please Try Later")
```

**Kivy Code**

**Basically i am trying to increase the count variable after the rewarded video played.**

```
            Screen:
                name: 'rewarded'
                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        font_style: 'H1'
                        theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                        text: "Counter "+str(app.Count)
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    icon: 'plus'
                    elevation_normal: 2
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
                    on_release: 
                        app.ads.show_rewarded_ad()
```

This code seems to be very big but you there are much irrelevant code I added it because for more transparency for the contributor.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works
There are some errors i fixed in my code and this is the Right implementation of KivMob Rewarded Video Listener.

So Let me Explain You Guys How to implement callback functions .

Firstly Make a Seperate Class for Handling Rewards Callback functions like I did with the

**Rewards_Handler Class** and Inherit it with RewardedListenerInterface Class.

Why I created the another class is to override the predefined Rewards Callback functions in RewardedListenerInterface Class in KivMob Library.

There are Total of 8 functions which you can override in KivMob library under RewardedListenerInterface Class.

You can find the function parameters and details about what it do here [here](http://kivmob.com/kivmob.html)

Override the functions by defining them with same name as in KivMob library.

Now the Last Step is to Plug this Class to your Code by passing the object in  set_rewarded_listener(YOUR_REWARDS_CLASS_OBJECT_HERE())